# How to use HEAD to check if file exests

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, angular8

I want to use this Spring Endpoint to upload a file.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<StringResponseDTO> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("id") Integer merchantId) throws Exception {
        ..............
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new StringResponseDTO("test"));
    }
```

Angular code:

```
imports(file: any, id: number) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    return this.http.post(environment.api.urls.merchants.uploadLogo, formData, {
      params: { id: id.toString() }
    }).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

In my case I want to display a download link into Angular if the file is present. How I can make a request using the HEAD and check if the file is present? 
I don;t want to download the file in order to verify the the file if available for download.

Comment: you want to display the link for the file just loaded or all existing files ?

Comment: yes - if the file exists.

Comment: Please read my answer and let me know if it addresses your issue.  Off the bat I see two glaring issues with your code ( namely the fact that your service is defined as a POST service, and you invoke your service using a POST method ).  In addition to that I think you may want to question your use of head in general, and you want to only return headers if you do choose to stick with head

Answer (score 0):

## HTTP Request Methods

Before addressing your question[s] directly I want to address the concept of an HTTP Request Method's in general.  An HTTP Request Method is used to **indicate** the desired action to be performed on the identified resource.  The following methods are standardized to some extent

- GET
- POST
- HEAD
- OPTIONS
- PUT
- DELETE
- PATCH
- CONNECT

What the resource represents and how you actual implement the service and invocation of the service ( the request ) is completely up to you.

> With that being said, it would be accurate to say that a GET request that is used explicitly to update an existing value is implemented incorrectly.
>
> Additionally, what method you choose will be limit your functionality if you are using any type of client-side or server-side platform or library.  For example, Angular won't provide a means of sending a request body with a GET, even though you technically could craft an HTTP GET call that contains a request body.

## Spring Boot

Looking at your code you explicitly set your service as a POST service with the following code

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
```

You can explicitly specify your service as a HEAD service by swapping that line with the following

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.HEAD, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE } )
```

However, remember that a HEAD method should basically be a GET method but should only return headers.  In the sample provided I cannot tell what your DTO does specifically, but it appears to be returning a body. Instead you can return only headers using something like

```
String fileId = ....
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set("fileId", fileId);

return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders);
```

The naming convention you are using is not RESTful.  Firstly, `/upload` endpoint is not resource oriented because there is no resource specified in your path.

Additionally *uploading* is probably not the correct verb to use, since what you're actually doing is *checking* or *validating*.  I would probably swap the endpoint for something like

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "/resourceName/validate", method = RequestMethod.HEAD, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE } )
```

Replacing *resourceName* with the name of your resource.

## Angular

Likewise in your Angular call your invocation is explicitly POST

```
return this.http.post( ... )
```

Similarly Angular has an $http.head method

```
return this.http.head( ... )
```

Unlike Spring Boot, you may not be able to simply swap out line for line though.  You will need to make sure that the parameters in head match the parameters in post, and if not you will need to adjust accordingly.

## Summary

My answer can be summarized as follows

- You may want to rethink your use of HEAD in general ( does it apply here? )
- You may want to rename your endpoint to be resource-oriented
- If you do want to use head you need to change your Spring Boot annotation
- If you do want to use head you need to change your Spring Boot response to only include headers
- If you do want to use had you need to change your Angular request to use the head method